# No video is written in for some part of video as the segmentation from FFmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am segmenting a 20 minutes long video to hundreds of small clips . The command is like

```
ffmpeg\\ffmpeg -i nx_1.avi -ss 399.37 -t 1 ka1_2.avi
```

The ffmpeg is in a subfolder.

It works very well for most of my video files. The problem is one file, for that file, some segmented clip only has audio, the relevant video obviously not was written into the clip. (Attached the log file below.). But the segmented clips in other part the video are good. Both audio and video are ok. I tried to segment a longer clip to encircle the problematic part of the original video and replay it. The clip plays fine until the problematic part, it froze at the beginning of the problematic part.

I use ffprobe to probe the avi, it says ODML index invalid. I guess this is the problem.

How can I solve this problem?

---

Log File:

```
ffmpeg started on 2013-05-07 at 10:29:33
Report written to "ffmpeg-20130507-102933.log"
Command line:
"ffmpeg\\\\ffmpeg" -i nx_1.avi -ss 399.37 -t 1 ka1_2.avi -report
ffmpeg version N-51683-g9dc88ac Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr  8 2013 21:22:02 with gcc 4.8.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 25.100 / 52. 25.100
  libavcodec     55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavformat    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 49.101 /  3. 49.101
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'nx_1.avi'.
Reading option '-ss' ... matched as option 'ss' (set the start time offset) with argument '399.37'.
Reading option '-t' ... matched as option 't' (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument '1'.
Reading option 'ka1_2.avi' ... matched as output file.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file nx_1.avi.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: nx_1.avi.
[avi @ 007c8f40] Format avi probed with size=2048 and score=100
[avi @ 01d9b800] use odml:1
st:0 removing common factor 400000 from timebase
[avi @ 007c8f40] File is truncated adjusting duration
[avi @ 007c8f40] ODML index invalid
[avi @ 007c8f40] ODML index invalid
[avi @ 007c8f40] ODML index invalid
[avi @ 007c8f40] ODML index invalid
[avi @ 007c8f40] ODML index invalid
[avi @ 007c8f40] ODML index invalid
st:1 removing common factor 4 from timebase
[avi @ 007c8f40] ODML index invalid
[avi @ 007c8f40] non-interleaved AVI
[avi @ 007c8f40] File position before avformat_find_stream_info() is 64668
[avi @ 007c8f40] parser not found for codec dvvideo, packets or times may be invalid.
[avi @ 007c8f40] parser not found for codec pcm_s16le, packets or times may be invalid.
[avi @ 007c8f40] parser not found for codec dvvideo, packets or times may be invalid.
[avi @ 007c8f40] parser not found for codec pcm_s16le, packets or times may be invalid.
[avi @ 007c8f40] All info found
[avi @ 007c8f40] File position after avformat_find_stream_info() is 3733036
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'nx_1.avi':
  Duration: 00:04:05.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7187 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 1, 1/25: Video: dvvideo (dvsd / 0x64737664), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1, 1, 1/48000: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file ka1_2.avi.
Applying option ss (set the start time offset) with argument 399.37.
Applying option t (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: ka1_2.avi.
Successfully opened the file.
[buffer @ 007c6fe0] Setting entry with key 'video_size' to value '720x576'
[buffer @ 007c6fe0] Setting entry with key 'pix_fmt' to value '0'
[buffer @ 007c6fe0] Setting entry with key 'time_base' to value '1/25'
[buffer @ 007c6fe0] Setting entry with key 'pixel_aspect' to value '16/15'
[buffer @ 007c6fe0] Setting entry with key 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'
[buffer @ 007c6fe0] Setting entry with key 'frame_rate' to value '25/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 007cdda0] w:720 h:576 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/25 fr:25/1 sar:16/15 sws_param:flags=2
[AVFilterGraph @ 01d9b2e0] query_formats: 4 queried, 3 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[abuffer @ 007c6f60] Setting entry with key 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[abuffer @ 007c6f60] Setting entry with key 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[abuffer @ 007c6f60] Setting entry with key 'sample_fmt' to value 's16'
[abuffer @ 007c6f60] Setting entry with key 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph 1 input from stream 0:1 @ 007ca880] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[aformat @ 007cde40] Setting entry with key 'sample_fmts' to value 's32p,fltp,s16p'
[aformat @ 007cde40] Setting entry with key 'sample_rates' to value '44100,48000,32000,22050,24000,16000,11025,12000,8000'
[aformat @ 007cde40] Setting entry with key 'channel_layouts' to value '0x4,0x3'
[audio format for output stream 0:1 @ 007ca940] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted resampler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'audio format for output stream 0:1'
[AVFilterGraph @ 007c9740] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 3 already done, 0 delayed
[auto-inserted resampler 0 @ 007ca9a0] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:48000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16p r:48000Hz
[mpeg4 @ 021f0060] detected 8 logical cores
[mpeg4 @ 021f0060] intra_quant_bias = 0 inter_quant_bias = -64
[dvvideo @ 007ccd60] detected 8 logical cores
Output #0, avi, to 'ka1_2.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.1.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/25: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1, 0, 3/125: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      10kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A    
EOF on sink link output stream 0:0:default.
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
[libmp3lame @ 021f0440] Trying to remove 47 more samples than there are in the queue
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=      27kB time=00:00:01.03 bitrate= 213.5kbits/s    

video:0kB audio:16kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 66.787791%
[AVIOContext @ 01d9a200] Statistics: 10 seeks, 51 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 01d98d20] Statistics: 1566764528 bytes read, 16520 seeks
```

Comment: I found the reason by myself. The video is greater than 4G. I download the 64bit FFmpeg. Then it seems everything is fine now. The ODML index invalid message is kind of misleading.